# Xamarin KeyStore is lost

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play, google-play-console

I have formatted my development machine without due to hardware failure and haven't backup my keystore files now I need to update my app in google play but it refuse because of signing difference.
I will try : **"Upgrade app signing key"** but what is the better choice in my case ?
I have chosen **"I need to use the same key for multiple apps, or a pre-installed version of this app"**
in this option they ask to download a PEPK tool and run this command

```
$ java -jar pepk.jar 
--keystore=foo.keystore 
--alias=foo 
--output=output.zip  
--signing-keystore=uploadkey.keystore 
--signing-key-alias=upload-key-alias 
--encryptionkey=encryptionkey
```

My problem is that visual studio creates only one keystore according to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows
and in the command line two keystores are required so where to find them??

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset the key for you to a different keystore and then you will be able to publish future updates.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.

Comment: I dont know about this method, I will keep in mind, thanks!